# Stop http interceptor to overwrite the headers passed from service layer angular

Tags: angular, http, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I have an API which send data as plain text. I need to pass { responseType:'text'} in the service layer but it's not reaching to the interceptor.
How to pass headers & responseType for a particular API so that it reaches to interceptor and based on API URL,can pass header came from service layer ?

Interceptor code-

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    console.log("request", request.headers);
    const token = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (token && token.token) {
        if (!request.url.includes("testAPI/")) {
          const newRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token.token}`,
            }
          });
          return next.handle(newRequest);
        } else {
          const newRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token.token}`,
              "Content-Type": "text/plain",
              Accept: "text/plain",
              responseType: "text",
            }
          });
          return next.handle(newRequest);
        }
      
    }
  }
}
```

Service Code-

```
testFunction(token) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

    headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    headers = headers.set('Accept', "text/plain");
    return this.apiSrv.get(TEST_API, {headers:headers,responseType:'text'});
 }
```

It works after disabling http interceptor and passing options like below. responseType parameter should be passed separately from header to make it work.

```
{headers:headers,responseType:'text'}
```

but i don't want to disable/remove interceptor. When i enable interceptor it either overwrites the headers passed in service or headers are not reaching to the interceptor. i passed headers in testFunction but when i debug it shows.

[image]

Pleas guide me . how to make it work ?

Comment: you can put condition in interceptors to check which request url is sending plain text request and by pass those request inside interceptors

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Thanks for quick reply. I have already put the conditions based on API URL but passing responseType in header doesn't work. i don't know how to pass responseType separately from header. it works when passing header & responseType separately like below  -return this.apiSrv.get(TEST_API, {headers:headers,responseType:'text'});

Comment: You can pass headers either in service testFunction or inside interceptors, if you do in both , then interceptors overwrites headers.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda right. i passed headers in interceptor like below & it worked. Thank yo so much. const newRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token.token}`,
              "Content-Type": "text/plain",
              Accept: "text/plain"
              
            },responseType: "text",
          });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed headers in interceptor like below & it worked.

```
const newRequest = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: Bearer ${token.token}, "Content-Type": "text/plain", Accept: "text/plain" },responseType: "text", });
```